# Probability that the circuit will not fail

Tags: probability, combinatorics

When connected to the network circuit each element fails with a probability of 0.8. Find the probability that the circuit will not open at the time of inclusion.

[image]

Using basic formulas I got answer 0,83: P(X)=$0,8+(1-0,8^2)^2-0,8(1-0,8^2)^2$

Answer (score 1):

The upper branch works when both the subsystems work, thus with probability

- $(1-0.8^2)\cdot(1-0.8^2)=0.1296$

the lower branch fails with probability

- $0.8$

The system is in parallel thus it work always but both branches not working, thus

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{The System Works}]=1-(1-0.1296)\cdot 0.8=30.37\%$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a parallel circuit with two paths. If any of the path does not fail, the circuit remains connected.

The upper path fails if at least one of the two loops in the upper path fails. Probability that a loops fails is $0.8^2 = 0.64$ and that a loop does not fail is $0.36$. So the probability that at least one of the loop fails is $1 - 0.36^2 = 0.8704$.

Hence the probability that the upper path fails is $0.8704$.

Probability that the lower path fails is $0.8$.

So the probability that the circuit does not fail is $(1 - 0.8704 \times 0.8) = 0.30368$.